# Exchange. How to forward mail, not save it

Tags: exchange, migration, exchange-2016, exchange-migration

We are migrating mail from one of our domains to the exchange (123123.com). We created users in AD, created mailboxes for them and copied mail from Google there. Also the domain was added to accepted.

Now other users of other domains from the exchange are trying to write a letter to the addresses of the domain that we are migrating.
The exchange puts the received letter to itself, but I need it to be forwarded to Google servers.

How to make the exchange send a letter for the domain further to Google, but not save it?

I tried to make a Send connector for the domain, I tried to change the UPN and SMTP for users, I tried to disable mailboxes - it was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have configured forwarding recipient or email address for all users, you could run the following command that messages are delivered only to the specified recipient or email address, and messages aren't delivered to this mailbox.

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity "usermailbox" -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $false
```

For more details: [Use the Exchange Management Shell to set up mail forwarding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/user-mailboxes/email-forwarding?view=exchserver-2019#use-the-exchange-management-shell-to-set-up-mail-forwarding) and [-DeliverToMailboxAndForward](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailbox?view=exchange-ps#:%7E:text=%24false%3A%20If%20a%20forwarding%20recipient%20or%20email%20address%20is%20configured%2C%20messages%20are%20delivered%20only%20to%20the%20specified%20recipient%20or%20email%20address%2C%20and%20messages%20aren%27t%20delivered%20to%20this%20mailbox.%20If%20no%20forwarding%20recipient%20or%20email%20address%20is%20configured%2C%20messages%20are%20delivered%20only%20to%20this%20mailbox.)

Comment: No, I did not set up forwarding.

We are migrating domain and mailboxes from google to the exchange. There are boxes like 123 @ 123123 on the exchange. MX records from the internet are set to google.

I need the exchange not to process mail for the 123123.com domain, but to forward it to Google servers.

Comment: I have found a similar thread for your reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/426745/email-dual-delivery-between-exchange-server-and-go.html   And it may be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks. It took all this time to try it. It really helped. I set up another external domain for Google, created contacts with this domain on the exchange and redirected mail from the exchange to the new Google domain.
Thank you so much, you gave me a direction for a solution. You are the best